# Regex to check if "=" or "|" exists between (?<=P_MFG_PART_NUM\=) and (?=\|P|$)

Tags: .net, regex

I am struggling to identify whether a string contains "=" or "|" between delimiters (?<=P_MFG_PART_NUM\=) and (?=\|P|$).

I am able to match all characters using this (?<=P_MFG_PART_NUM\=)(.*?)(?=\|P|$). Not sure how to check if the inside string has just "=" or "|".

A typical string will look like the below and I am trying to identify the = or |. The start of the match string should be "P_MFG_PART_NUM=" and end can be "|P" or end of line

> X_MFG_PART_NUM=|X_MANUFACTURER_ID=|X_ORGANIZATION_ID=|X_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=|X_RETURN_STATUS=Validation
>   failed|P_MFG_PART_NUM=**HEX, 1/2-13 X 4 IN THD = NC TP316-SS, ASTM
>   A312**|Psdfsdfs

The regex will be executed in .net.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might first match all the chars that are not followed by either `|P` or the end of the string `$` using a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) approach `(?:(?!\|P|$).)*`

Then match either a `|` not followed by a `P` or match an equals sign `(?:\|(?!P)|=)`

```
(?<=P_MFG_PART_NUM=)(?:(?!\|P|$).)*(?:\|(?!P)|=).*?(?=\|P|$)
```

In parts

- `(?<=P_MFG_PART_NUM=)` Assert what is on the left is `P_MFG_PART_NUM=
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!\|P|$).` If what is on the right is not `|P` or end of string, match any char
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\|(?!P)|=` Match either `|` not followed by `P` or match `=`
- `)` Close group
- `.*?(?=\|P|$)` Match as least as possible and assert `|P` or end of string on the right

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dP_MFG_PART_NUM%3d%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5c%7cP%7c%24%29.%29*%28%3f%3a%5c%7c%28%3f!P%29%7c%3d%29.*%3f%28%3f%3d%5c%7cP%7c%24%29&i=X_MFG_PART_NUM%3d%7cX_MANUFACTURER_ID%3d%7cX_ORGANIZATION_ID%3d%7cX_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID%3d%7cX_RETURN_STATUS%3dValidation+failed%7cP_MFG_PART_NUM%3dHEX%2c+1%2f2-13+X+4+IN+THD+%3d+NC+TP316-SS%2c+ASTM+A312%7cPsdfsdfs%0d%0a%0d%0aX_MFG_PART_NUM%3d%7cX_MANUFACTURER_ID%3d%7cX_ORGANIZATION_ID%3d%7cX_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID%3d%7cX_RETURN_STATUS%3dValidation+failed%7cP_MFG_PART_NUM%3dHEX%2c+1%2f2-13+X+4+%7c+IN+THD+NC+TP316-SS%2c+ASTM+A312%7cPsdfsdfs%0d%0a%0d%0aX_MFG_PART_NUM%3d%7cX_MANUFACTURER_ID%3d%7cX_ORGANIZATION_ID%3d%7cX_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID%3d%7cX_RETURN_STATUS%3dValidation+failed%7cP_MFG_PART_NUM%3dHEX%2c+1%2f2-13+X+4+%7cPsdfsdfs+IN+THD+%3d+NC+TP316-SS%2c+ASTM+A312%7cPsdfsdfs%0d%0a%0d%0aX_MFG_PART_NUM%3d%7cX_MANUFACTURER_ID%3d%7cX_ORGANIZATION_ID%3d%7cX_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID%3d%7cX_RETURN_STATUS%3dValidation+failed%7cP_MFG_PART_NUM%3dHEX%2c+1%2f2-13+X+4+IN+THD+%3d+NC+TP316-SS%2c+ASTM+A312%7cPsdfsdfs%0d%0a%0d%0aX_MFG_PART_NUM%3d%7cX_MANUFACTURER_ID%3d%7cX_ORGANIZATION_ID%3d%7cX_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID%3d%7cX_RETURN_STATUS%3dValidation+failed%7cP_MFG_PART_NUM%3dHEX%2c+1%2f2-13+X+4+IN+THD+%3d+NC+TP316-SS%2c+ASTM+A312%0d%0a%0d%0aX_MFG_PART_NUM%3d%7cX_MANUFACTURER_ID%3d%7cX_ORGANIZATION_ID%3d%7cX_INVENTORY_ITEM_ID%3d%7cX_RETURN_STATUS%3dValidation+failed%7cP_MFG_PART_NUM%3dHEX%2c+1%2f213+X+4+IN+THD++NC+TP316-SS%2c+ASTM+A312Psdfsdfs%0d%0a%0d%0a&o=m)